# PHP, MYSQL workbench, postman not working correctly

Tags: php, foreach, mysql-workbench, postman

I have 2 users in a table, for example Vesna and Silvija, Vesna is first, Silvija second and if I type Silvija in postman he will return me "User does not exist and than Id of a user Silvija. This should be working on a way that Postman return just an Id of a User and if I type user that doesnt exist he should return that user doesnt exist. But when I type a users that doesnt actually exist he will return 2 times that users doesnt exist instead one time because table have 2 users that doesnt match entered user. Hope I have explained it understandably and that someone can help me.

```
    foreach($oUsers as $oUser)
    {
        if($oUser->USERNAME == $sUsername)
        {

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $oUser->USER_ID;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $oUser->USERNAME;
            echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
            break;



        }

        else
        {

            echo ' User does not exist';

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `echo '...'` inside the foreach loop because `echo` is executed in every iteration.

```
$found = false;
foreach($oUsers as $oUser){
    if($oUser->USERNAME == $sUsername){
        $_SESSION['user_id']  = $oUser->USER_ID;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $oUser->USERNAME;
        $found                = true;
        break;
    }
}

if($found === true){
    echo $_SESSION['user_id'];
}else{
    echo ' User does not exist';
}
```